# Restrict solidity function as only callable by another function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether, remix, etherscan

How can I make a solidity function to be only callable by other functions in the same contract? and it doesn't visible in etherscan or remix as a normal function.

Eg:

```
contract Calc {
      function add(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint) {
                return adder(a,b);
             }
      function adder(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint) {
                return (a+b);
          }

}
```

here I need to make the function 'adder' is only accessible to other function like 'add'. but i can't be accessed by the user through remix or etherscan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function adder(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint) {
                return (a+b);
          }
```

simply change the visibility of your `adder` function from `public` to `internal` or `private`

`public` means the function is accessible from the inside and outside.

`internal` means the function is accessible only from within the contract himself and contracts inheriting from that contract.

`private` means the function is only callable within the very smart contract.